# FluentValidation Validate numbers max length

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I Have to validate the max length of an int or long with FluentValidation

I want to use something like this

```
int PortCode = 4444;
RuleFor(x => x.PortCode).NotEmpty().MaximumLength(10);
```

but FluentValidation does not support it

what is the solution;

Comment: You can assign more that int32.MaxValue to int i.e. 2,147,483,648... Should you using `InclusiveBetween` or `ExclusiveBetween` methods?

Comment: Mention **FluentValidation** version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use this custom validation

using FluentValidation;

```
public static class ValidationHelper
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, short> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, short> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs((double)n)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, short?> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, short?> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs((double)n.Value)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, int> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, int> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs((double)n)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, int?> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, int?> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs((double)n.Value)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, long> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, long> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs((double)n)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, long?> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, long?> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs((double)n.Value)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, decimal> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, decimal> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs((double)n)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, decimal?> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, decimal?> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs((double)n.Value)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, double> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, double> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs(n)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, double?> MaximumLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, double?> rule, int maximumLength) => rule.Must(n => Math.Log10(Math.Abs(n.Value)) <= maximumLength).WithMessage("The length of '{PropertyName}' must be '" + maximumLength + "' Digit or fewer.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need custom validation

you can do this instead

`RuleFor(a => a.PortCode).NotEmpty().Must(w => w.ToString().Length < 10);`

Comment: This will end up with converting and a very big performance issue